# How to set starting page in .NET Core C# and AngularJS

Tags: .net, angularjs, .net-core

I am working on a project and I need to use .NET Core for backend, cuz of the http services and other things. Everything works with the requests but I have a front-end problem. I am trying, with AngularJS, to open a specific page. You know, when you open a .NET Core app it shows you ip:localhost/api/values and I don't want that I want my index.html, actually my dashboard.html

Here is my code, so:

**index.html, file that is located in main folder, not wwwroot**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>titlu</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<ui-view></ui-view>

<!-- LLIBRARIES -->
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="wwwroot/app.js"></script>
<script src="wwwroot/dashboard/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

**my app.js witch I use with AngularJS to set a default route, dashboard.html**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    var dashboard = {
        name: "dashboard",
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "./dashboard/dashboard.html"
    };

$stateProvider.state(dashboard);
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
});
```

and my dashboard.html is a basic html page.

I tried different things, like

> app.UseDefaultFiles(); app.UseStaticFiles();
>   but it dose not work for me.

Any help would be awesome.
Thank you so much !!!

Comment: do you have views in your .Net core application?

Comment: Can you please tell me the type of .NET Core project you created. Was this API or Web Application or Web Application (MVC) or Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can have this in your Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                  IHostingEnvironment env, 
                  ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     app.UseStaticFiles();
     app.UseMvc(routes =>
     {
           routes.MapRoute("spa-fallback", "{*anything}", new { controller = "SPA", action = "Index" });
           routes.MapWebApiRoute("defaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
     });
}
```

After, you can create the SPAController and serve the index.html on Index() method:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return File("~/index.html", "text/html");
}
```